# C Format String printf("%lld") wrong results

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

```
long long temp_number;
float input = 0.7f;
temp_number = input*100;
printf("%lld",temp_number);
```

Could anybody explain why do i get 69 instead of 70?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Its because `0.7` can't be represented exactly in binary. Its binary representation may be equivalent to `.69999999999` in decimal. Therefore `.6999999999*100` = `69.99999999`.

Comment: So in Computer Science is not possible to multiply 0.7*100 and get correct results? :-)

Comment: Why not? Try this:  `temp_number = input*100 + 0.5;`.

Comment: You can get correct results in Computer Science. You can't get infinitely accurate results in IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic. That's why you shouldn't use IEEE-754 where you need infinite accuracy.

Comment: Correct results for such FP calculations can be obtained easily if you have infinite RAM.

Comment: @haccks  The `input*100 + 0.5` approach fails when `input < 0`.  Better to use `temp_number = round(input*100);`.

Comment: @chux is `round` a standard function? It has only appeared in recent versions of MSVC.

Comment: @Weather Vane Yes, `round()` is specified in C99 and C11.  Good to know it is available in MSVC too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing mysterious here. It is similar to writing `1/3` as a decimal `0.333333~` ( `~` meaning "recurring") and then multiplying by `3`. The answer is `0.999999~` not `1`, and I hope you can see this has nothing to do with computer science.

You have converted the `float` to `long long int` and the compiler warns that doing so might result in loss of data. But you multiply by 100 before converting to a different type, so let's look at the `float` example more.

The decimal value `0.7` cannot be exactly represented in binary `float` format. When you use `printf` with `float` it rounds up the least significant bit of the mantissa to deal with the problem. So when I do this

```
float f = 0.7f;
printf("%f\n", f);
```

the output is `0.700000` which I wanted. But when I multiply the `float` value by 100, that creates a bigger error in the least significant bit of the mantissa, which previously was only in error by `1`. So now using

```
float f = 0.7f;
printf("%f\n", f*100);
```

the output is `69.999999` because rounding the least significant bit up does not make the number roll up to `70.000000`.

Returning to the first example of the decimal representation of `1/3` but in a finite storage size, say 10 decimal digits as `0.333333333`. Multiplying by `3` gives `9.999999999` and rounding up the last digit is will produce `1.000000000`. But multiplying by `30` gives `9.999999990` and rounding up the last digit is not going to produce `10.00000000`.

The C language does not "know" that the `float` representation of the number truncates a recurring fraction. Perhaps there is a numerical type that can hold this information and compute arithmetical functions accordingly.

Comment: Some details: "printf with float it rounds up the least significant bit" is amiss.  `printf()` rounds the x.xxxxxx result to the nearest 0-9 _decimal digit_, not _bit_.  So `0.7f` or `0.6999999881...` goes to `0.700000` and `printf("%f\n", f*100);` goes to `69.999999`